# Aircraft Roll Discretization

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm working through this FAA [Aircraft Dynamics Model](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ang/offices/tc/activities/tgf/media/AircraftDynamicsModel.pdf) paper and struggling to understand their derivation discretizing the linear system describing Roll rate and angle vs. the desired angle.

On page 61 they give the system for the critically-damped case ($\zeta=1$, eq 2.163) with roll rate `p` and roll angle $\phi$:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} p(t) \\ \phi(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{-\omega_nt}-\omega_nte^{-\omega_nt} & -\omega_n^2te^{-\omega_nt} \\ te^{-\omega_nt} & e^{-\omega_nt}+\omega_nte^{-\omega_nt} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p(0)\\\phi(0)\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\omega_n^2te^{-\omega_nt}\\1-e^{-\omega_nt}-\omega_nte^{-\omega_nt}\end{bmatrix}\phi_{des}
\end{equation}$$

On page 62 they state that discretizing the system for a 0.5 sec time step with $\omega_n=2 rad/sec$ becomes:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} p(k+1) \\ \phi(k+1) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.9606 & -0.0392 \\ 0.0098 & 0.9998\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p(k)\\\phi(k)\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0.0392\\0.0002\end{bmatrix}\phi_{des}(k)
\end{equation}$$
but I do not understand how they came up with those values.

At the beginning of the section they state `Because the equation is linear, no numerical integration technique need be applied` but it seems obvious that they're not simply substituting $\omega_n=2$ and $t=0.5$ into 2.163, as the $A_{11}$ expression would reduce to $e^{-1}-e^{-1}=0$.

I'm probably missing something obvious since it's not explained in the text as far as I can tell. Hopefully someone can help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Their values are consistent with $t = 0.01$. I am not sure why there is a discrepancy.

Comment: Indeed it looks like they calculated for a timestep of 0.01 rather than 0.5, Great catch, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is as simple as substituting the values into 2.163, but their values are for $t=0.01$ rather than 0.5 as it says in the text.

Great catch @[eyeballfrog](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/395748/eyeballfrog)!